# PHP Fibers return null values

Tags: php, fibers

While running below code, it return empty values. I have used fibers to run the code and used PHP version is 8.2

```
<?php
  
$data=["A","B","C"];
$fibers = [];
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $fiber = new Fiber(function () use ($val): void {
        Fiber::suspend($val);
    });

    $fiber->start();
    $fibers[] = $fiber;
}

$results = [];
foreach ($fibers as $fiber) {

    $results[] = $fiber->resume();
}

print_r($results);
?>
```

Expected Output

```
Array
(
    [0] =>"A" 
    [1] =>"B"
    [2] =>"C"
)
```

While running above code return this output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

Comment: First of all, enable displaying all errors, then I guess, you'll see some warning message

Comment: @InDevX nope...demo: https://3v4l.org/OMdGo#v8.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to `$fiber->start();` consumes your `$val`.
As per documentation the return value of `start()` is the variable given to the first `Fiber::suspend()` call or null if the function returned. `resume()` does the same, so your call to `start()` already returned `$val` and then there is nothing left for `resume()`.

The result you want would be achieved with this code:

```
<?php
  
$data=["A","B","C"];
$fibers = [];
foreach ($data as $val) {
    $fiber = new Fiber(function () use ($val): void {
        Fiber::suspend();
        Fiber::suspend($val);
    });

    $fiber->start();
    $fibers[] = $fiber;
}

$results = [];
foreach ($fibers as $fiber) {
    $results[] = $fiber->resume();
}

print_r($results);
?>
```

And here a suggestion for a rewrite while still using Fiber:

```
<?php
  
$data=["A","B","C"];
$fibers = [];

$callback = function ($val): string {
    Fiber::suspend();
    return $val;
};

foreach ($data as $val) {
    $fiber = new Fiber($callback);
    $fiber->start($val);
    $fibers[] = $fiber;
}

$results = [];
foreach ($fibers as $fiber) {
    $fiber->resume();
    $results[] = $fiber->getReturn();
}

print_r($results);
?>
```